# Stackdriver logs not available for Cloud ML jobs since migration to V2

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-ml

Since migration to V2 logs from Cloud ML jobs are not accessible on the Stackdriver logging console anymore. The last log displayed is

```
Waiting for Tensorflow to start.
```

The job is executed and completed successfully, I just can't access outputs in the logs

All Stackdriver APIs are enabled for the project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report. We will investigate and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no known issues with Cloud ML's Stackdriver logging. The fact that you see "Waiting for Tensorflow to start." indicates you are seeing log messages from Cloud ML.

If logs from your Python/TensorFlow program are missing that usually indicates Cloud ML hasn't been authorized to send logs to Stackdriver logging for your project. To check permissions do the following

1. Identify the Cloud ML service account by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets#step_1_get_required_information_from_your_cloud_project)
2. In the Cloud Console select the IAM Tab
3. Verify that the Cloud ML service account is listed and has **Logs Writer** permissions

Comment: The job completes successfully. I access the Stackdriver UI either from the link returned in Cloud Datalab when I start the job or from the jobs console.

Comment: Can you please explain what logs you are expecting to see and not seeing? Does the Cloud ML Service account have write access for Stack Driver Logging for the project? These [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets#step_1_get_required_information_from_your_cloud_project) explain how to identify the service account. In the Cloud console you can select the IAM account and see what permissions have been granted.

Comment: Yes it does. I think I couldnt write checkpoints and summaries without it. It worked with V1

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly are the logs you are expecting to see and not seeing?

Comment: I expect to see the output of Tensorflow: TF warning, TF errors, and logs sent by `tf.logging.info/warn`, as it was before with V1. Now, I only have logs from Cloud ML ( before TF starts, after TF stops)

Comment: What is the V2 migration you are referring to?

Comment: Please see the screenshot taken from the job logs page

Comment: I think that is a coincidence.  Stackdriver has migrated to V2 and there are no known issues with V2 and Cloud ML. There are a couple possibilities here; 1. either the logs aren't being sent to Stackdriver or 2. there is a problem in the ui. Assuming you are accessing it from the Cloud ML UI 2 is unlikely. Are you customizing the logger? Could you try submitting a simple program like [this](https://gist.github.com/jlewi/4849ac6cb6aea75db17a27298e3e633e) as the training job and seeing if logs show up.

Comment: It's not the UI. Logs aren't available from the gcloud neither. Tensorlfow outputs a lot of logs at startup + some warnings. The day the stackdriver UI changed, they all disappeared. Without having changed a line in my tf program.

Comment: Can you please try running the simple program?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to verify the Cloud ML service account has logs writer access. I'd suggest confirming that Logs Writer access is enabled is that is by far the most common cause of logs not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

This problem also took me two weeks to search answers online with frustration, until I came across this post. I did not see "migration to V2" as OP mentions but I simply could not get any application logs in StackDriver, only system logs of job started/completed. Following what Jeremy replies solves the problem.

To make Jeremy's reply simpler to follow, essentially you add the ML service account

`cloud-ml-service@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

to your project's IAM members, with at least "Logs Writer" role.

You can get "project-id" by:

`gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)"`

I also assigned Project->Editor role to allow Bucket access.