# Tensorflow/Cloud Datalab : Restore called with invalid save path

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-ml

I am training a model in the Cloud with Cloud ML from a Cloud Datalab notebook.
I'd like to evaluate the model locally with.

```
%mlalpha train
package_uris: $package_path_local
python_module: trainer.task
args:
  eval_data_paths :  ...# local or gs://
```

I all cases (local or remote I get the following error:

```
Restore called with invalid save path: u'[path to checkpoint file]'. File path is: u'[path to checkpoint file]'
```

However evaluating on the cloud works fine. Tensorflow version in latest Cloud Datalab is 0.11rc0

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

1. your training model graph and evaluation model graph are different. Check to make sure you are using the same model.
2. You trained a model, then changed the model, and tried to train or evaluate again. You may need to delete the checkpoint directory so that things start afresh.

Answer (score 0):

You were running "%mlalpha train" command, so it is training but not evaluation? Or does your code in training package try to load a checkpoint?

When the evaluation worked in cloud, what command did you run?

Comment: If no training data is sent, it runs an eval pass on the files `eval_data_paths` using the code that runs periodic evaluations on the validation set during training. The problem is that [logs are broken on the cloud](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41185588?noredirect=1) so I have to run the eval locally

Comment: It seems there is a behavior change in tensorflow between the version in Datalab and the version running in service. Try upgrading tensorflow to: http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Release/job/release-debian-cpu/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl. (run !pip install [url] in a cell) and see if it works now.