# Tensorflow on ML Engine: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I launch a tensorflow task on ML Engine and after about 2 minutes I keep getting an error message "**The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1.**"

(The task incidentally runs fine with ml-engine local.)

Question: Is there any place or log file where can I see further information on what happened?

The logs viewer just gives the following:

```
{
 insertId:  "ibal72g1rxhr63"  
 logName:  "projects/**-***-ml/logs/ml.googleapis.com%2Fcnn180322_170649"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-03-22T17:08:38.344282172Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "cnn180322_170649"    
   project_id:  "**-***-ml"    
   task_name:  "service"    
  }
  type:  "ml_job"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1."  
 timestamp:  "2018-03-22T17:08:38.344282172Z"  
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Have you checked https://console.cloud.google.com under machine learning / jobs (and then click on the job) to see check the memory usage? Is there any other info in Stackdriver logs before or after the error (sometimes stack traces can be several lines higher).

Comment: I did have a look and found nothing that helped further.  The preceding two entries are "Waiting for job to be provisioned." and "Waiting for TensorFlow to start." The one following the error is simply "Job failed."

I wonder if there is  a way of capturing more information, have the master node write some logs/debugging info? 

From further tests I guess my problem may be related to the way I try to get some Python dependencies installed (via a setup.py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the apparent lack of log files was missing permission to write to the logs.

Under IAM & admin, adding the **Logs Writer** role the account `cloud-ml-service@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` solved the problem and enables the master and workers to write log messages to Stackdriver as expected.

For a similar discussion and some additional information, see [Stackdriver logs not available for Cloud ML jobs since migration to V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168116)

Thanks to all for giving input!

Comment: Thank you so much! Have no idea how I would have figured this out otherwise. For me the account to add was the same account I had to add to the cloud storage (which was given to me directly through cloud shell)

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver agents can monitor many metrics and give details about ML engine. For more details, please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-ml). AFAIK, Normal event logging and Stackdriver agents are the only tools to monitor the ML jobs on GCP.

Please note that Python 2.7 which is used in Tensorflow works with relative imports. It is possible that you locally used Python 3.4 which worked with absolute imports. That is why it worked locally but not on Google Cloud. You can refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249119/difference-in-package-importing-between-python-2-7-and-3-4) to modify your import statement. So, if you include the line `“from __future__ import absolute_import”` at the top of your code, before the line “import tensorflow as tf” , your code may work.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the core issue (some modules missing and/or dependency issues). Generally, I still fail to use logging with ML Engine, though. E.g., if I add `tf.logging.set_verbosity('DEBUG')` and `tf.logging.info("logging test")` to my trainer, I still see no messages in the Stack driver log except for the 7 standard messages (`Validating job requirements... | Job creation request has been successfully validated | Job  is queued | job to be provisioned. | Waiting for TensorFlow to start | Job completed successfully.`) Does this work for anyone? (2.7 Python, ML runtime-version 1.5)