# The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1(GCP Tensorflow error)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am using the recommendation engine tutorial available [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-overview). I am exactly following the code but I am encountering an error(error log details given below) while running

```
./mltrain.sh train ${BUCKET} data/ratings.dat --delimiter ::
```

The error log details are

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 206, in <module> main(job_args) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 31, in main args, input_file, args['data_type']) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 80, in create_test_and_train_sets input_file) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 116, in _ratings_train_and_test 'timestamp': np.int32, File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 498, in parser_f return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 275, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 586, in __init__ self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 665, in _clean_options raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators, but this causes 'dtype' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine. (Note the 'converters' option provides similar functionality.) To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=570527225445&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fwals_ml_train_20190916_150714&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%
```

I am following the below code

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git bzip2 unzip
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-recommendation-wals
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
cd tensorflow-recommendation-wals
conda create -n tfrec
conda install -n tfrec --file conda.txt
source activate tfrec
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install tensorflow
curl -O 'http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-1m.zip'
unzip ml-1m.zip
mkdir -p data
cp ml-1m/ratings.dat data/
```

my bucket name is re_bucket

```
BUCKET=gs://re_bucket
gsutil cp -r data/ratings.dat $BUCKET/data/ratings.dat
cd wals_ml_engine
./mltrain.sh train ${BUCKET} data/ratings.dat --delimiter ::
```

I have tried several solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434874/tensorflow-on-ml-engine-the-replica-master-0-exited-with-a-non-zero-status-of-1) but still getting the same error. I have also created several complete new instances many times to see whether that can resolve the error or not but there is no success in that. Please let me know what are the possible steps that I can follow to resolve issue.

Note: When I am trying the same thing in my local storage using

```
./mltrain.sh local ../data re_data.dat --delimiter ::
```

things are working fine for me. It might be the case that error is related with GCP bucket.

Also attaching the screenshot for stack driver information

[image]

Comment: What do the logs show as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: It says The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1

Comment: No other information in Stackdriver?

Comment: this is the last message fron stackdriver ? Let me know in case you want more information{
 insertId: "8c7k7bcnhc"  
 logName: "projects/recommendation-engine-l/logs/ml.googleapis.com%2Fwals_ml_train_20190916_174421"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-09-16T17:49:18.828172120Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "INFO"  
 textPayload: "Job failed."  
 timestamp: "2019-09-16T17:49:17.913990690Z"  
}

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the problem with stack driver information. Hope this might be helpful