# Google AI Platform: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 127

Tags: google-cloud-ml

There's a similar SO question: [Tensorflow on ML Engine: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434874/tensorflow-on-ml-engine-the-replica-master-0-exited-with-a-non-zero-status-of-1)

But here, I'm encountering error "127" instead. Similar to that question, I launched a pytorch custom training container on AI Platform (previously ML Engine) and after about 2 minutes I get the error message "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 127".

The documentation here doesn't quite say what "127" means: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting#understanding_training_application_return_codes

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It usually means that your training process exited with non-zero exit code (i.e. a user error). You can check the job logs to find the root cause.

Comment: It's indeed a problem with the code we supplied to Google AI Platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I was using `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` in the **Dockerfile**.

Let's use `ENTRYPOINT` like this [document: Train an ML model with custom containers](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/train-ml-model-custom-containers#using_gpus_with_custom_containers)

```
#CMD ["python", "trainer/mnist.py"]
# failed -> the replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 127

# Try ENTRYPOINT!
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "trainer/mnist.py"]
```

This solution may not be the cause in your case though, It may be good idea to check if the cause is a Dockerfile or not 
It may be useful to check the differences between the sample Dockerfile in the above link and your own Dockerfile.